# Which contact sheet generator can be scripted?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, scripts

A contact sheet is a image containing the name and a the small version of a group of images, like this:

[image: example of a contact sheet]

Which is the best program to do it from the command line (preferably something that is already package with Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 2):

`montage` (part of the `imagemagick` package) can do this.

The options are exhastive so i thoroughly recommend running `man montage` but here's an example [I pulled](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/is-there-an-easy-way-to-print-a-photo-contact-sheet-675428/) to show off the perverse level of detail you can go into:

```
montage -size 400x400 ~/Pictures/2008/Sept/*.JPG  -thumbnail 200x200 -font /var/lib/defoma/gs.d/dirs/fonts/Vera.ttf  -set caption '%t' -bordercolor Lavender -background grey40  -gravity Center   -pointsize 9  -density 144x144  +polaroid  -resize 50%   -set label ''  -background white  -geometry +1+1  -tile 5x  index.html
```

It makes both a webpage and a contact image.

Comment: Thanks for your perverse example, but I think a simple example would be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

For interactive use, `feh` takes the prize, especially if you're dealing with a lot of images. `feh -t images...` and you're off. Has options to easily control thumb and total sizes, and the thumbs are clickable through to the real thing.

For printing, `feh` works, but `montage` (as per @Oli's suggestion) is probably more dependable as it handles more image formats than `feh`.

For completeness I should mention that `gimp-plugin-registry` has a plugin for Gimp ("Contact Sheet 2.0") that produces contact sheets from a directory of images, which is relatively user friendly.